# .htaccess check for specfic query string attribute

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

We are changing a sites' structure and the old urls look like:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/pages.php?PageId=7
```

The new url is:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/niceurl
```

And I have this .htaccess that comes with the CMS I am using so the core functionality of it cannot be made to work differently.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

</IfModule>
```

What I *really* want to do is check if pages.php is getting requested and if so ignore the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Then after this rule do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^PageId=7(.*)$ /niceurl [R=301]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(PageId=7)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PageId=7
RewriteRule .* /niceurl? [R=302,L]

</IfModule>
```